# Error while creating pivot on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am facing error in last like while creating a pivot table on SQL Server. 
Following is the code:

```
SELECT 
    COL1, 'X'
FROM
    (SELECT COL1, COL2
     FROM TABLE_X 
     WHERE COL3 = 'B' AND COL4 = 'Activation') AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (COUNT(COL1)
     FOR COL2 IN ('X')
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'X'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is giving an error at line "count(Col1) "and line "for col2 in ('X') as Invalid Column name.

Comment: IN ([pivot_value1], [pivot_value2], ... [pivot_value_n]) etc ..you need to specify the values of x

Answer (score 0):

Column `COL1` will not exist in the Pivot result since it is the Aggregated column.

you can change this example to just

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT COL1, COL2
     FROM TABLE_X 
     WHERE COL3 = 'B' AND COL4 = 'Activation') AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (COUNT(COL1)
     FOR COL2 IN ([X]) -- put the values in square brackets instead of single quote
    ) AS PivotTable
```

and you should only get a single column back named `X`